# Master Theorem rule about constraint

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Essentialy T(n) = a*T(n/b)+f(n)
There is this rule where it says "b" cannot be expressed as a constant ie. T(sqrt(n)). What does it mean that "b" cannot be a constant. Isn't be always a constant?

Comment: T(sqrt(n)) isn't a constant, it's a function of n.

Comment: Sorry to say that better: sqrt isn't a constant, particularly sqrt(n)  can't be expressed as n/b (which is what is required here)

Comment: oh that makes so much sense